# How to instantiate different instances of a svelte component in a single parent component every time the child component is used?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I am creating a custom select menu in svelte and have encountered an issue while trying to edit the transform property of the downward icon for the select menu.

I am creating a form with multiple select menus imported to one parent component. Whilst clicking on the second select menu box used in a parent component file, only the first select menu box's icon gets transformed, while no change occurs in the position of the icon of the second select menu box.

I think that this is because both the imported components(select menu) share the same class during compilation. If my assumption is correct, is there any way to instantiate an instance of the select menu component in the parent component every time the select component is used?

```
<script>
  export let displayText;

  let clickCount = 0;
</script>

<div
  class="selection"
  on:click={() => {
    clickCount++;
    clickCount == 1
      ? (document.querySelector(".arrow").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)")
      : (document.querySelector(".arrow").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)");
    clickCount == 2 ? (clickCount = 0) : (clickCount = clickCount);
  }}
>
  <span>{displayText}</span>
  <div class="arrow" />
</div>

<style>
  .selection {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #363636;
    font-size: 14px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .selection .arrow {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: There this thing called "boolean" which has the possible values `true` or `false`, there is no need to count clicks.

Comment: Please show the code that actually uses the component.

Comment: The code which uses the component only imports it. All the functions and stylings with respect to the component are present in the code shared above.

Comment: That makes no sense. Unless the component is placed somewhere, its code will not run, nor will its elements exist. You have to insert it somewhere. An obvious problem with the code is `querySelector`, which should *not* be used in Svelte.

Comment: My apologies for the poor question. I am habituated to the primitive methods of handling UI elements in vanilla js. I am a newbie to svelte and any other javascript frameworks, due to which it is taking time for me to change my approach in manipulating the UI. Nevertheless, in the near future, I shall try to avoid asking such lame questions.

Comment: If you have not done so already, you should check out the [interactive tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial), it shows most features quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `document.querySelector(".arrow")` that will always find the first element with the class. Svelte has other tools to avoid that and target and manipulate element inside the component without querying the DOM. Here you can use the [`class:` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b78ba71decda44cca8f8850b2d146fd2?version=3.52.0)

```
<script>
    export let displayText;

    let open = false
</script>

<div class="selection"
     on:click={() => open = !open}
     >
    <span>{displayText} - open = {open}</span>
    <div class="arrow"
         class:rotated={open}
         />
</div>

<style>
    .selection {
        ...
    }
    .selection .arrow {
        ...
    }
    .rotated {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
</style>
```